# Possible reason for discrepancy in keras h5 model confidence and the same model converted to tflite?

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

Recently I used keras to transfer train the mobilenet model. I reconfigured the output layer to predict on two classes.

I then converted the saved .h5 file to a .tflite file. Once ran in Android Studio according to TensorFlow's ImageClassification example:

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification

I am seeing small discrepancies in the confidence of the predictions. I.e.

For this image: 
[Image that inference was ran on][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSmLp.jpg

**Tflite model confidence:** 
[2.0677739E-5, 0.9999794]

**Inference on .h5 desktop using Keras predict:** 
[5.100073E-4, 9.994900E-1]

As you can see they predict in the same general direction. I am however curious about what could possibly cause the discrepancy?

In case this is not as simple as a general explanation I will post all code that is required.

**Versions desktop:**

```
TensorFlow 2.1.0
Keras 2.3.1
Keras-applications 1.0.8
keras-preprocessing 1.1.0
```

**Versions android:**

```
'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.1.0'
'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:0.0.0-nightly'
'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-support:0.0.0-nightly'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow Lite could have a slight difference from keras model since they don't share the same runtime kernel. Also it happens if the tflite model is quantized.

Comment: Unless they explicitly converted it somewhere in the example I think it remains float. But I will look into the code some more and read about the kernel. It is a good start. Thanks.